# How To Connect mysql Database to multiplay PCs in Client machine?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, desktop-application

After I finished my 1st Desktop Programme by python which is used to add Office information in Database

My client had 4 computers belong to 4 employees who will use this programme.

My client has a Local Server and his IT told me that I can use these server to link database to 4 computers.

So after installing my exe programme on 4 computers it is not working as I expect.

How can I connect database to exe in 4 computers? i.e when 4 empolyees update or delete or add in database, database will effected.

These is part of code which I connect database.

I am using MySQL Workbench.

```
def Connect_DB(self):
    # Connect to Data base
    self.db = MySQLdb.connect(db='office', user='root', password='mysql', port=3306)
    self.cur = self.db.cursor()
    print('Database connected')
```

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a unified visual tool for database architects, developers, and DBAs.   so how are you using Wiorkbench and what for  It is the other way around you connect the clients to the mysql server and all have the same host and can have different users.

Comment: How can I connect my database to my-exe-prog  in 4 computers?

Comment: add  host="ip of mysql sever", to your connect and you should have access, when the rest is correct credentials database port